# Excel VBA: Searchfunction

Tags: excel, vba

I have already created the following code with a search function. Now I have several problems. Im an beginner so please be kind :)

When I hide columns, the cell in which I enter the search is also hidden. => I would like to replace it with a text box and don't know how to modify the code for that, or it doesn't work for me.
So far, the cell "SearchCriteria" where I enter the search term is also colored yellow; however, the format of the cell or the text box should be retained.
It would be great if multiple search terms could be used. For example: Term1, Term2, and if both occur in one row/cell, it should be highlighted or filtered.

**Worksheet Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("SearchCriteria")) Is Nothing Then Call SearchAndMarkUIDPCR
End Sub
```

**Module Code:**

```
Dim markedCells As Range

Sub SearchAndMarkUIDPCR()
    ' Check if the search criteria is empty
    If Trim(Range("SearchCriteria").Value) = "" Then
        ' If the search criteria is empty, show all rows in the table
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        ' Before resetting, check if there were previously marked cells
        If Not markedCells Is Nothing Then
            ResetMarkings
        End If
    Else
        ' Before filtering, reset all previously marked cells
        ResetMarkings

        ' If the search criteria is not empty, enter values for the filter
        shFilter.Range("A2, B3, C4, D5, E6").Value = "*" & Range("SearchCriteria").Value & "*"

        ' Apply advanced filter
        Range("tbluidpcr[#All]").AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, shFilter.Range("A1:E6")

        ' Highlight search term
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim searchTerm As String

        ' Set the target worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        ' Set the search term
        searchTerm = Range("SearchCriteria").Value

        ' Search the entire range of the table
        Set rng = ws.UsedRange
        For Each cell In rng
            If InStr(1, cell.Value, searchTerm, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                ' Highlight the cell with the search term
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' Change RGB values as needed
                ' Add the marked cells to the list
                If markedCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set markedCells = cell
                Else
                    Set markedCells = Union(markedCells, cell)
                End If
            End If
        Next cell

        ' Check if there were previously marked cells
        If Not markedCells Is Nothing Then
            ' Reset cells that no longer match the search criteria after filtering
            For Each cell In markedCells
                If InStr(1, cell.Value, searchTerm, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                End If
            Next cell
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub ResetMarkings()
    ' Check if there were previously marked cells
    If Not markedCells Is Nothing Then
        ' Reset the background color of previously marked cells
        markedCells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        ' Clear the list of marked cells
        Set markedCells = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

I just tried ChatGPT but i didnt solved any of the problems.

It would be great if you could send me a Code or give me direction how to solve my problem